# How to change VPN credentials on Windows10?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, credentials

How to update password for existing VPN connection on Windows 10.

Where I can find current VPN's **usernames** and how is possible to **update it's password** ?

**Edit:**

For me, VPN password change didn't automatically pops up when connecting through clicking on network icon on taskbar. *Maybe it's issue of VPN provider.*

I did the reset through `Settings > VPN > "CLick on specific VPN" > Advanced > Clear sign-in info` and now the popup on next connect is shown.

Comment: If the password has already been changed, you will be prompted for the new password, when you attempt to connect using the old password

Comment: Hm.. not sure why but no popup is appearing

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Settings** and search for **VPN**. You should find "*Change virtual private networks (VPN)*".

There you should see the VPN you are looking for. Click on it and then click on *Advanced options*.

There you can see the user name. Click on *Edit* to update the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround:

- go to **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections**
- Right click, select properties, options tab, and uncheck **Remember my credentials**
- Next time you try to connect you will be asked for new credentials.
- If you want to remember your credentials again, check Remember my credentials again, and it will be remembered next time when you type in credentials